# Meteor Image Display Not Working Once App Is Deployed

Tags: image, meteor

Currently I am creating an application where I display an uploaded file from CollectionFS and display it using the CollectionFS url return. Locally the image loads and is displayed. However once I deploy the application to meteor.com the image url does not work. With the console indicating that the image path cannot be found.

CollectionFS returns this url for my image:
/cfs/contacts/75erhMtuwjn66fQH3_default1.png

Locally when I deploy the app I can see the image using in my .html:
img src="/cfs/contacts/75erhMtuwjn66fQH3_default1.png"

The specific code returned by CollectionFS is in the .html file and is being called client side:

`{{cfsFileUrl "defaultHandler" fileId=fileId collection="Collection"}}`

Locally I use this address as the source for the uploaded image in my html:

localhost:port/cfs/contacts/75erhMtuwjn66fQH3_default1.png

But when I attempt to view the image of the deployed app using the same procedure, it returns with an error of url not found:

`http://host.meteor/cfs/contacts/75erhMtuwjn66fQH3_default1.png.com`

A file is added on a click event client side .js:

`'change .fileUploader': function (e) {`

```
var files = e.target.files;
var fileName = files[0].name;
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      var k = ContactsFS.storeFile(f);
      Session.set('fileID', k);
}}
```

Server side:

`ContactsFS.fileHandlers({
  default1: function(options) {`

```
return { 
    blob: options.blob, 
    fileRecord: options.fileRecord // if no blob then save result in fileHandle (added createdAt)
};
```

}});

Then I can call the url in html with the given function from collectionFS documentation:
{{cfsFileUrl "default1" fileId=fileId collection="ContactsFS"}}

Once again the problem isn't generating the url. Both locally and once deployed the app displays a url. It is using the image url as the source for the image tag that is giving me the problem.

Comment: you should provide some code and maybe describe the steps you took. Did you upload the image on the remote host or did you try the same URL as on the client?

Comment: revision made. please keep asking questions until my problem is clear

Comment: you must have a router method that listens to the URL ´/cfs/contacts´ can you please post that. Also: do you use the same database on both client and server? If not, the file might have a different name on the server

Comment: see edits listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CollectionFS had a bug. I contacted the creator with the issue and it is now resolved in the collectionFS package. The report and closed issue can be found at:
 https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/85